# calculating skew angle using openCV in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm trying to perform OCR for business cards, and I am trying to pre-process the image, and Image rotation/Deskewing is one of the step.

I'm using openCV to do this.

Here is the image with some angled text:

[image]

output:

[image]

I did some research and found that , calculating skew angle can be improved by calculating contours and creating a flood filled image.

I did try that one as well, and here is the image resulted by flood filling:

[image]

floodfill_threshold:

[image]

flood fill_inverse:

[image]

grayscale pic of floodfill_threshold:

[image]

**Code to calculate skew angle:**

```
cv::Mat tempMat2 = im_floodfill.clone();//Tried with all three image results
cv::cvtColor(cvImage2, tempMat2, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::bitwise_not(tempMat2, tempMat2);

UIImage *invertImg5 = [self UIImageFromCVMat:tempMat2];//just to see the image

//Calculating Skew angle
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
cv::HoughLinesP(tempMat2, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, size.width / 2.f, 30);
cv::Mat disp_lines(size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
double angle = 0.;
unsigned nb_lines = lines.size();
for (unsigned i = 0; i < nb_lines; ++i)
{
    cv::line(disp_lines, cv::Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
             cv::Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), cv::Scalar(255, 0 ,0));
    angle += atan2((double)lines[i][3] - lines[i][1],
                   (double)lines[i][2] - lines[i][0]);
}
angle /= nb_lines; // mean angle, in radians.

UIImage *newImg = [self UIImageFromCVMat:disp_lines];

return angle;
```

**Code to rotate:**

```
//Got the angle and now rotate the image as per the angle
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = cvImage.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = cvImage.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
        points.push_back(it.pos());

cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, angle, 1); //angle

cv::Mat rotated;
cv::warpAffine(cvImage, rotated, rot_mat, cvImage.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

The number of lines are 575 and the output image is still same:

[image]

For a moment I ignored this output image, and cared about skew angle which is 21 degrees,

The resulting image is :

[image]

and when I try to rotate the negative 21, result is:

[image]

This is not what I hoping for. I'm not sure why the calculated skew angle is wrong.

One thing I have no idea is the line height parameter in

```
cv::HoughLinesP(tempMat2, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, size.width / 2.f, 30);
```

I have used 30 here, but i'm not sure how to calculate that number based on the image(business card image).

What am I missing here ?