# Unable to change the mat type in opencv

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm trying to change the type of Mat to CV_8UC4 from CV_8UC1.

```
cv::Mat tempCVImg2;
cv::Mat tempMat3;
cvImage2.convertTo(tempCVImg2, CV_8UC4);
tempMat2.convertTo(tempMat3, CV_8UC4);

NSString *strType1 = [NSString stringWithCString:type2str(tempCVImg2.type()).c_str()
                                        encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
NSString *strType = [NSString stringWithCString:type2str(tempMat3.type()).c_str()
                                       encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

cv::cvtColor(cvImage2, tempMat2, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

It crashes at cvtColor as it is expecting CV_8UC4 but received CV_8UC1.

Why cvImage2.convertTo(tempCVImg2, CV_8UC4); is not changing the type of mat cvImage2 ?

Answer (score 1):

It is written in the [documentation of `convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810)

Which states:

> rtype desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since the
>   number of channels are the same as the input has; if rtype is
>   negative, the output matrix will have the same type as the input.

as you can see the number of channels WILL be the same.

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve... but OpenCV does not know what data to put in the other channels extra and as far as I know there is no direct method.... if you want to duplicate the data you can use `cvtColor` with the `GRAY2RGBA` flag or something similar it will create the extra channels with the same values.... you can try also to use the `merge`or `mixChannels`... you should avoid resize + reshape, since the data must be:

```
 C1 C2 C3 C4, C1 C2 C3 C4....
```

This means that the data is organize with the 4 values per pixel, thus the C1 should be from each of them. I think if you tell what are trying to do, the answer could be a little more accurate.

Comment: I posted a question of what I'm trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792790/calculating-skew-angle-using-opencv-in-ios. In process of doing it, I encountered this error.

Comment: hmmm, still I do not see why you need to go from BGR to greyscale and then to 4 channel image?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=convertscaleabs#cv.ConvertScaleAbs)

```
convertScaleAbs(image);
```